# Does liftweb have iteration tags?

Tags: scala, iteration, jsp-tags, lift

I was wondering, does Lift have an iteration tag (ex: for, foreach)?
When I was working with JSP, i could easily iterate a List, just with JSP, passing the object to the tag. Something like [this](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jsp-foreach.shtml), or [like this](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/jsp/jstl-forEach.jspx).
I know it's not really the best example, but you do understand my intentions.
To sum up, does this exist with Lift, or if not, how would I manage to do such thing?

The last thing i want to do is hardcode html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short: No. Lift’s design strictly separates logic from design and as such forbids the use of generalised tags in the template markup.

Have a look at the [view first article](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/View_First) in order to see how lift can handle iterations.

An example from the article: Your markup:

```
<table>
  <lift:show.users>
    <tr>
      <td><f:first_name>David</f:first_name></td>
      <td><f:last_name>Pollak</f:last_name></td>
    </tr>
  </lift:show.users>
</table>
```

Your code:

```
class Show {
  def users(xhtml: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = 
    Users.findAll.flatMap(user => 
      bind("f", xhtml, 
        "first_name" -> user.firstName, 
        "last_name" -> user.nameName
      )
    )
}
```

Now, what lift does when it sees the tag `<lift:show.users>` is calling the corresponding method with the tag’s content as the argument. The tag will then be replaced by the return value of the `users` method.

The `users` method does the iteration over all `Users` and for each user, it `bind`s the values of first and second name to the inner `xhtml`. All those iterations are then concatenated (through `flatMap`) and returned.

When I started with lift, I’d always found this approach a little too rigid; having a tiny loop here and there, how could that possibly hurt? But now that I know how easy it is to call *and* create your own snippets from the template code, I cannot imagine using anything like jsp anymore. It is weak in comparison and clutters your markup. And of course, you lose much of Scala’s power of validation.

**Notes:**

The reason the template tags are filled with content is for designing purposes. In this case the dummy tags and values are going to be replaced during the `bind`. The template designers can thus fill the tags with more or less meaningful content which allows the coder to better understand the semantics the designer had in mind.

Comment: Why is "David" and "Pollack" in there?

Comment: Because it’s copied from the Lift wiki.

Comment: Will it print out his name for each user?

Comment: No, when it iterates over `Users` it will bind `user.firstName` to `<f:first_name>David</f:first_name>` and replace tag plus content with the plain name of the real user. One could also preserve the content, though.